# I want to initiate a bash child process and when assign child PID to an array the command {./child2.sh &} won't execute

Tags: linux, bash, fork, child-process

I want a simple linux program to create 6 child process using a for loop and capture each of the child PID in array. The problem is if I assign the command to variable the command `{./child2.sh &}` won't execute anymore.

I tried doing something like

```
cid[$i]=./child2.sh &  cid[$i]=./child2.sh & cid[$i]=./child2.sh &
```

Comment: Storing commands in variables doesn't work well. Fundamentally, variables are for storing *data* not executable code (functions are for storing code). See ["BASH: Unavoidable wordsplitting in subcommand expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421967/bash-unavoidable-wordsplitting-in-subcommand-expansion) and [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) BTW, some people suggest `eval` to solve this, but it just makes the parsing process even more confusing and tends to cause even weirder bugs.

Comment: I don't see why you first want to store strings representing a command into an array, and then execute the command explicitly by typing its name. Also, "won't execute" is not really a very helpful error description. The code which you posted, does not make much sense: It first does a variable assignment in a background process, and then assign in the foreground the same variable twice with the identical value.

Comment: pardon, removed those quotes "" , ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pid of the latest program launched in background in stored in `$!`. Try the following:

```bash
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
  ./child2.sh &
  cid[$i]=$!
done
```

To get the exit status of the terminated processes, use `wait`command:

```bash
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
  ./child2.sh &
  cid[$i]=$!
done

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
  wait ${cid[$i]}
  echo "Status of child#$i (${cid[$i]}): $?"
done
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly what I needed!

Comment: and is there anyway I can get the Exit status of each child using this Child pid array? I know $? gives the exit status of last command but I want exit status very specific to child? is there anything the wait Child_pid reports about that?

Comment: @KaleemKhattak [`wait`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-wait) can take the PID of a specific child process to wait for. Its exit status will be the exit status of that process.

Comment: ok For the exit status i created another for loop that waits for each process and gathers the exit code for each process like exit_status[j] = $?.

Comment: @KaleemKhattak, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question makes no sense whatsoever. It never captures `$!` and it is unclear what `i` and `cid` are supposed to represent or why some of the commands (including the trailing `&`) are in quotes.

To track the whereabouts of a few `fork`ed off background processes, you can capture their PIDs using `$!` and then wait for them to see if they succeeded:

```bash
# A useless process that does nothing and then maybe fails.
child() { sleep "$1"; echo "sleep ${1} done"; return "$(($1 % 2))"; }

# Start 6 processes. Store PIDs in a sparse array (because we can).
for ((i = 1; i <= 6; ++i)); do child "$i" & pids["$!"]="$i"; done

# Wait for all background processes in any order.
while ((${#pids[@]})); do
  wait -n -p pid && echo -n 'Succeeded:' || echo -n 'Failed:'
  echo " child ${pids[pid]}"
  unset 'pids[pid]'
done
```

Comment: pardon, removed those quotes "" , ''